# Backbone.js - Get specific value from JSON file

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

(edited for more Info)

I am creating a Pizza Builder app in Backbone.js. Now what I want is when a specific model is clicked ( doing that with e.currentTarget();) I want to append the description from that model to a different step-by-step div.

All the data is fetched within a Successhandler but i don't know how to get the specific description for the specific ingredient. I hope someone can help me out.

```
**Ingredient Model**
site.models.Ingredient = Backbone.Model.extend({
defaults: {
    "name": 'Ingredient',
    "sort": 'None',
    "description": "Default",
    "price": 0,
    "bake-time": 0,
    "vegetable": ""
}});


**Ingredient Collection** 

site.collections.IngredientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: site.models.Ingredient,
url: "js/Ingredients.json"});


**Ingredient View**

site.views.Ingredient = Backbone.View.extend({
description: '',

price: '',

events: {
    "click p": "ingredientClicked"   //Call ingredientClicked function
},

initialize: function(getInfo){
    this.ingredientTemplate = getInfo.ingredientTemplate;
    this.getIngredients(); //Load the Ingredients Function

},


//Call a handler when an ingredient is clicked!
ingredientClicked: function(e){
    var chosenIngredient = $(e.currentTarget).data('ingredient'); //Get Current Target (Name that's clicked)
    console.log(this.appendIngredient);

    console.log(chosenIngredient);
    $("#ingredients").append("<li>" + chosenIngredient + "</li>"); //Append to our div!

    this.appendIngredient();
},


//Load all ingredients asynchronous
getIngredients: function(){
    this.collection.fetch({
        success: _.bind(this.loadIngredientSuccessHandler, this),
        error: _.bind(this.loadIngredientErrorHandler, this)
    });
},

loadIngredientSuccessHandler: function(data, json){
  for (var i= 0; i < json.length; i++){
      data = {
          ingrName: json[i]['name'], //Haal naam uit JSON op
          ingrSort: json[i]['sort'], // Haal soort uit JSON op
          ingrDescription: json[i]['description'], //Haal Beschrijving uit JSON op
          ingrPrice: json[i]['price'],
          ingrBakeTime: json[i]['bake-time'],
          ingrVegi: json[i]['vegetable']
      };



      //Create a template and append it to $el.
      var template = _.template(this.ingredientTemplate.html(), data, this);
      this.$el.append(template);


  }
},


appendIngredient: function(data){
    this.description = data.ingrDescription;
    $("#steps").append(this.description);
},

//Error handler if something went wrong
loadIngredientErrorHandler: function(collection, response, options){
    console.log("If something went wrong!")
}});
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question right.
You basically need to render a new instance for each ingredient when fetched, and call the description in the view by using:

```
this.model.get("description");
```

Since the model is bound to the view, you don't need to access the DOM to get the ingredient.

Edit:
What I think you're looking for is that you fetch the collection first: this will return a collection for which each ingredient is represented by a model (with id, name, description). Then you loop through the collection and instantiate a new view for each model, after which you can access the model within the views by calling `this.model.get("description");`.

Note: check out Backbone Marionette; this makes it very easy to render collections.

Comment: Yeah my bad sorry! I am pretty new to Backbone and was wondering if using a JSON file is better then just add them normally to my model.

Comment: Check the edit, see if this clarifies something for you.